# Accessing PHPMyadmin from all IPs in EC2 running on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 running in AWS. I have  installed  LAMP. everything works as expected. 
Now if my IP to access phpMyadmin get changed because of my location or wifi change or network change ..

I am not able to access phpMyadmin and I always get forbidden error.

I am not able to find solution this problem.

I searched through stackoverflow . there are very questions on this topic.  I tried all the answers but didn't get a resolution.

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share knowledge its the below modification to 
/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyadmin.conf

that solved the problem.

```
 <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

But i also read , somewhere that its not a good idea to allow phpmyadmin access from everywhere. I m new to phpMyAdmin. So experts are welcome to comment.

Thanks